# Suma de un número repetido en un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

Suponiendo que tengo una columna en un DataFrame de Pandas con los números `1, 2, 3 y 4` repetidos varias veces. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para sumar los números únicos? Por ejemplo, si quiero la suma de todos los `4` que se encuentran en dicha columna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba con:

```
df['columna'].value_counts()
```

te dará cuantas veces se repite el valor. Después lo multiplicas y debería dar el resultado esperado